# How to get the data on screen after movened event is triggered

Tags: carto, events

I am displaying 100 cities on the map. [image: pic 1]

After zoom or move the map, only e.g. 9 items are displaying on the current screen.

[image: pic 2]

So how can I get these data from my dataset? Especially the object id?

Following is the code to create layer:

```
var sql = new cartodb.SQL({ user: 'achilles' });
        var query = "SELECT * FROM mi_munv5 where objectid in (" + ids + ")";
        layer.setSQL(query);
```

Comment: Can you elaborate better your question? It's not clear what you want to achieve. You show a couple of screenshots (I see nothing wrong in them) but it's not clear how they relate to what you want to do. I think you want to download or display on your web alphanumeric information from the data displayed on the map?